# How do I embed a javascript player in ionic?

Tags: ionic3

Hi Im working on an online radio station app using Ionic. Im struggling to embed the following player which works fine on a normal web page:

Please assist if anyone has a solution

Comment: here is the emebed code: <script src="https://embed.radio.co/player/b499a28.js"></script>

Comment: so do you struggle to import the library or?

Comment: Did you try to create a normal Ionic component out of this library?